# how to prevent the app be killed by "unmount media"(change to usb storage mode)

Tags: android

the app is downloading, and write the file to sdcard. then change the phone to usb storage mode, the app will be killed by system. because the app is using the sdcard. how to prevent this? or if there is some notification before killing ?

Answer (score 0):

The android platform does show a warning that some applications may stop working if used in USB storage mode.

I don't think there is any other way for the application to handle this. The application on the next run should determine if everything went alright last time.

Answer (score 0):

Don't allow the app to be moved to the sdcard so the app won't get killed.  If you are writing files to the sdcard during the time the external storage is unmounted, handle the errors that occur and/or monitor the sdcard mount/unmount broadcasts.

Comment: my app is not installed on the sdcard. and when the external storage unmount happened, the app is already be killed. there is not a chance to receive the broadcasts. that is the system sends the broadcast after the killing.

Comment: you mean the app is downloading in the background? and the user has moved on to some other task? note that at that point android can kill your app at any time - you should consider moving the download function to a service, and/or better handling in onStop/onPause/onDestroy

Comment: no, not like this. I know how to deal with it if the app be killed when running in the background. my scene is that the app is using the sdcard(like write file to sdcard), then change the phone to usb storage mode. the sdcard will be unmounted, the app using the sdcard will be killed.